# Implementing a client-side persistence manager in C++

Tags: java, c++, orm, persistence, intersystems-cache

I have a 2-tier application (a heavy client written in C++ which connects to the object-oriented database). The database itself is [InterSystems Cache'](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls), and it is actually *both* a *database* and an *application server* (*Cache'* is also a [MUMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) interpreter).

For performance reasons, I want to design a client-side *cache* (or, more generally, a *persistence manager*).

*InterSystems Cache'* does have "fast" interfaces like ODBC/JDBC, but I'm dealing with a lot of legacy client code which has already been using [Object Binding](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBCP_intro) for ages. So I can't change the architecture of the client, but have to make the protocol faster. The protocol itself is originally *very* verbose: all class/method/property names are sent verbatim, so, for instance, creating a single object server-side "costs" me 50k traffic.

Classes at the server side support inheritance and can have properties and methods. So using *Cache' Object Binding* means I can:

1. create and delete objects,
2. read and update properties, and
3. call methods.

What is important here, a server-side method call generally executes the code, the nature of which is unknown to the client. Since this code may potentially alter the state of the objects in the database, client-side cache may need to be invalidated after a method call. This is different from regular [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, where the client can keep track of changes he made to the objects, and update the cache accordingly.

Questions:

1. Which Java persistence managers are worth looking at, so that I can take the idea and reinvent the wheel? I'm thinking of [J2EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Bean) entity beans, [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), and in-memory grids like [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html).
2. Which C++ persistence managers can be adapted to use the InterSystems API? Particularly, are [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) a fit for my task?
3. Which methods can be used to "compress" the protocol which is originally very verbose on the wire? My first call is ZIP-compressing the traffic and hashing (encoding) class/method/property names (so that a [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) structure containing integers instead of names is sent over the network). Any other ideas?
4. What reading on Enterprise Patterns (particularly, in C++) applicable in my case can you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

ORM framework (Wt::Dbo) seems to do this job:

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo/tutorial.html

`Wt` looks like a very interesting tool to implement a modern web application in C++.

Comment: This is a borderline link-only answer. Link-only answers on this site are not really answers. Consider improving your post and use the link only as a reference.